# How save state of variable when change of html page

Tags: javascript, html

I do 2 actions when I click on a picture on a HTML page.
These 2 actions are:

- change a trigger (it's a specific action, and it works when I click)
- change a picture. (it works too)

This is **a part** of my HTML code :

```
<div class="col c1-11">
      <p><a onclick="return toggle(this);" data-on="/trigger/2" data-off="/trigger/3" href="/trigger/3"><img src="images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png" /></a></p>
</div>

<div class="col c1-11">
      <p><a onclick="return toggle1(this)" data-on="/trigger/4" data-off="/trigger/5" href="/trigger/5"><img src="images/mur1/V_2_OFF.png"></a></p>
</div>
```

This is **a part** of my javascript code :

```
function toggle(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');

  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png";
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png";
  }
    return false;
}

function toggle1(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');

  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_2_ON.png";
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_2_OFF.png";
  }
    return false;
}
```

I have 3 questions, I hope you can help me :-) :

- First question : Considering I have many pictures on my page, do I need one function for each picture? It will be very long I think.
- Second question : for example, I click once on my picture1 ; the picture on my screen become `"images/mur1/V_1_ON.png"`, no problem. 
  But if I left my page and I come again on this page, it reload and as default, the picture is `<img src="images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png" />`, like in my html code. How can I keep `"images/mur1/V_1_ON.png"` on the screen?
  Clearly, I must save the state of my `<img>` even if I change of html page.
  Do you know how can I do?
- Third question: When my html page appears on the screen, it is a little long because there are many pictures on the screen ; how can I do to make it faster?Preload pictures?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

***Considering I have many pictures on my page, do I need one function for each picture?***

Instead adding function for each picture . Attach event handler to images on the document with using name or class as selectors . So only one function is required.

***How can I keep "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png" on the screen? Clearly, I must save the state of my  even if I change of html page. Do you know how can I do?***

You may save which image is selected in HTML5 local storage . Then when loading the page check the storage and display the correct image.

***When my html page appears on the screen, it is a little long because there are many pictures on the screen ; how can I do to make it faster?preload pictures?***

Few options are listed below ,

1. You can implement CDN to make image retrive faster.
2. [Data URL](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) can be used for images
3. Caching can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part of your question, you can utilize a [web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). In your case, you need to save your images state after each click to the web storage and check on page load if there is a state in users web storage (i.e. with window.onLoad event).

As for the second part, I believe that the only thing you can do is to reduce image size.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need one function for each image. You need to keep track of what are your possible image `src`s for each image. You can either calculate that dynamically (which may be a little brittle, but will work if you adhere to your naming convention), or save that information on the image element itself (as another `data-` attribute).

   ```
   <img src="images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png" data-on="images/mur1/V_1_ON.png" data-off=images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png />
   ```
2. You can either use a server-side session and render the correct state server-side, or you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` client-side, and apply those state changes when the page loads.
3. You have X pictures you have to download; You can't really avoid that. However, you can use techniques like sprites to save on requests, as well as storing your images in an optimized and cached CDN.